# How To Replace Lines in a text File Stored in internal storage Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, writefile, internal-storage

Hey I am Using this Code But There Is A Problem, My File Is In my android device

Full Path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/File.txt";

The Problem Is Whenever i tried to run this code it gives me an error

"E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here."

"E/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so"

What Should i do

Thanks in advance guys

```
public static final String PATH ="/storage/emulated/0/Android/File.txt";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_file);
    File infile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), PATH);


    replaceSelected("Do the dishes", "1");

}



public static void replaceSelected(String replaceWith, String type) {

    try {

        File infile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), PATH);

        if (!infile.exists()) return;

        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));

        StringBuilder inputBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        String line;


        while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {

            inputBuffer.append(line);
            inputBuffer.append('\n');
        }
        file.close();
        String inputStr = inputBuffer.toString();

        System.out.println(inputStr); // display the original file for debugging

        // logic to replace lines in the string (could use regex here to be generic)
        if (type.equals("0")) {
            inputStr = inputStr.replace(replaceWith + "1", replaceWith + "0");
        } else if (type.equals("1")) {
            inputStr = inputStr.replace(replaceWith + "0", replaceWith + "1");
        }

        // display the new file for debugging
        System.out.println("----------------------------------\n" + inputStr);

        // write the new string with the replaced line OVER the same file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(infile);
        fileOut.write(inputStr.getBytes());
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Full Path = "Android/data/File.txt";` That is no full path to begin with. Its a relative path. Further it is quite a strange place for a .txt file. How did it land there?

Comment: Further you are nowhere using that 'path'.

Comment: `new FileReader("notes.txt"))` You should use a full path there. Not only a file name.

Comment: `new FileOutputStream("notes.txt")` Ditto. Use a full path only.

Comment: tried still same error

Comment: You should have posted your new code by now of course. How should we know what you did?

Comment: `public static final String PATH="Android/data/File.txt";` As said before: that is not a full path and you need to use full paths.

Comment: If you have adapted your code and want that i react you should call me. As i will not come back here again otherwise.

Comment: Also add: `if( !infile.exists()) return;`

Comment: is this ok Path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data"

Comment: Wel that looks like a valid full path and you can check if that path exists with new File( "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data").exists(). Now did you? And is your file really in that directory? Check with File.exists(). And you did again not call be so you were lucky..

Comment: Still E/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so

Comment: `Also add: if( !infile.exists()) return;` Why dont i see thyat in your code? Follow the comments please. This takes ages!!! aLSO PUT FULL PATH IN CODE!!!!!